# I/O System Call needs exit

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls, qtspim

If I do a i/o system call or more, when I finish I should do an exit call (code 10) or not is necessary?

I make an example:

```
      .data
      input_message: .asciiz "\nEnter an integer: "

      .text
      .globl main

   main:
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, input_message
      syscall

      addi $v0, $zero, 5
      syscall
      add  $t0, $zero, $v0

      addi $t0, $t0, 1

      addi $v0, $zero, 1
      add  $a0, $zero, $t0
      syscall

      [***]

      jr $ra
```

I should add an exit call in `[***]` position, something like this, or not?

```
      li $v0, 10
      syscall
```

Comment: The `jr $ra` should suffice if you are using the C runtime, which `main` hints at.

Comment: I use QtSpim to simulate mipsx86.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QtSpim (at least version 9.1.17 for Windows) places the following code at the start of the `text` section:

```
[00400000] 8fa40000  lw $4, 0($29)            ; 183: lw $a0 0($sp) # argc 
[00400004] 27a50004  addiu $5, $29, 4         ; 184: addiu $a1 $sp 4 # argv 
[00400008] 24a60004  addiu $6, $5, 4          ; 185: addiu $a2 $a1 4 # envp 
[0040000c] 00041080  sll $2, $4, 2            ; 186: sll $v0 $a0 2 
[00400010] 00c23021  addu $6, $6, $2          ; 187: addu $a2 $a2 $v0 
[00400014] 0c000000  jal 0x00000000 [main]    ; 188: jal main 
[00400018] 00000000  nop                      ; 189: nop 
[0040001c] 3402000a  ori $2, $0, 10           ; 191: li $v0 10 
[00400020] 0000000c  syscall                  ; 192: syscall # syscall 10 (exit)
```

As you can see, it will `jal` to your `main` label, and if you return with `jr $ra` it will perform the exit syscall for you.
So `jr $ra` is fine as long as you've preserved the original value of `$ra`. However, performing the exit syscall yourself might be required for other simulators (PcSpim, Mars).

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael!